# Passing selectInput values to map

Tags: r, shiny, gis

I am trying to figure out how to use variables selected through selectInput on the UI side to populate the map data on the server side. Although I've had some success manually setting variables to show up through filteredData, it doesn't work properly for inputs that can dynamically change. Is there some function/solution that could help subset the data to show on the map based on user input?

UI.R

```
districts <- readOGR("location",layer)
metadata <- read.csv("metadata.csv")

#Prepare list of values for the selectInput boxes
COMMUNITYSAFETY<-as.list(metadata$variable[metadata$group == "Community Safety"])
names(COMMUNITYSAFETY)=metadata$description[metadata$group == "Community Safety"]

##CONTINUED FOR REST OF SELECTINPUT BOXES

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Map"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("vr", "Would you like to show the variable by value or rank?",
                c("Value" = "_v",
                  "Rank" = "_r")
    ),
    selectInput("group", "Select Group:",
                c("Community Safety" = "COMMUNITYSAFETY",
                  "Demographics" = "DEMOGRAPHICS",
                  "Healthy People and Environments" = "HEALTHY_PEOPLE_ENVM",
                  "Housing" = "HOUSING",
                  "Income and Employment" = "INCOME_EMPL",
                  "Lifelong Learning" = "LIFE_LEARNING",
                  "Transportation" = "TRANSPORTATION")),
    #if user choses Community Safety
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.group == 'COMMUNITYSAFETY'",
      selectInput("var", "Community Safety Variables:",
                  COMMUNITYSAFETY)),

    #repeat other conditional panels for inputs

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(  
      tabPanel("Map", leafletOutput("map", height=800)),
      tabPanel("Histogram")
))))
```

Server.R:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  filteredData <- reactive({
    subset(districts,select=input$var)
  })

...

  observe({
    leafletProxy("map", data=districts) %>%
      addPolygons(stroke=TRUE,
                  fillColor=pal(filteredData()),
                  color="black",
                  weight=.5)
  }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, how you use `leafletProxy`. Type in `?leafletProxy` and you will see, that `leafletProxy` does not have any `data` parameter!

> leafletProxy(mapId, session = shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain(), 
>   data = NULL, deferUntilFlush = TRUE)

So, you need do add your `data` in you case `districts` in the second part you your code, namely here:

```
addPolygons(data = districts, stroke=TRUE,
    fillColor=pal(filteredData()),
    color="black", weight=.5)
```

What you should keep in mind is that your `districts` should be something `leaflet` understands. The help [page says](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shapes.html) that `leaflet` can display `objects` from the `spatial class` of the sp package. So you must convert your district into a `SpatialPolygon`.

Assuming your having a matrix with `lat lng` columns, where each entry is one of the nodes/points of you polygon, this function converts the matrix into the desired output for displaying on the map.

makePoly <- function(myMatrix) {

```
if (nrow(myMatrix) >= 3) {
    # create Polygon
    myPolygon <- Polygon(myMatrix)

    # create Polygon List
    myPolygonList <- Polygons(list(myPolygon), 1)

    # create spatial Polygon 
    # why? -> can have a CRS associated with it!
    myPolygonSpatial <- SpatialPolygons(list(myPolygonList))

    # assign CRS
    proj4string(myPolygonSpatial) <- CRS("+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs")

    return(myPolygonSpatial)

} else {
    print("Matrix to short")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is very simple, you can simply use the subset() function to subset the data and use the data for plotting.

Consider the following code:

```
districts <- readOGR("location",layer)
output$Map = renderLeaflet({
filterData = subset(districts, districts$variable = input$var)
mapStates = map("world",region= filterData$variable, fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)
mapa <- leaflet(mapStates) %>% addTiles()%>%
addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 0.5,color = "black") %>%
setView(lng = 31, lat = 35, zoom = 1)
})
```

Also, instead of "world" you can replace it with names of different regions/countires.

Hope this helps :)